# Is it possible to change the data point size for maloglog plots?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to change the data point size for maloglog plots in matlab?

I can do it for scatters plots with `scatter(X,Y,S)`.

But is it possible for maloglog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, generate your plot, say

```
h=maloglog(Red,Green,'title','Red vs Green','FactorLines',3,'LABELS',maStruct.Names);
```

To change marker shapes to `o`'s:

```
set(h,'Marker', 'o');
```

Or, to your question, to change size:

```
set(h, 'MarkerSize', 10)
```

Or, set 10 to whatever size you like.